# android service

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-asynctask, android-service

в своем приложении я храню данные в базе данных (sqlite). Для отображения я использую expandedlistview на активности. Для того чтобы не нагружать процессор обращениями к базе данных  я создал статическую переменную в сервисе,  в которой храню актуальные данные.

```
public class NetworkService extends Service
{
private static List<RouteTask> routeTaskList;

public static void setRouteTaskList(List<RouteTask> rtList)
    {       
        routeTaskList = rtList ;        
    }

    public static List<RouteTask> getRouteTask(){
        return routeTaskList;
    }
}
```

Загрузка данных с сервера происходит в AsynkTask

```
public class LoadRoutesTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, RoutesResponse> {

    private final String url = ApplicationSettings.SERVER_URL
            + ApplicationSettings.GET_ROUTE_DRIVER_DATE_URL;


    public LoadRoutesTask(Context ctx, TaskLoadListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(RoutesResponse result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected RoutesResponse doInBackground(Object... params) {

        String email = (String) params[0];
        String sessionID = (String) params[1];
        int pageSize = (int) params[2];
        int pageNumber = (int) params[3];
        String order = (String) params[4];
        long date = (Long) params[5];
        date = date - date % 86400000;


        // upload all status updates and remove them from pending in case succesfully
        AuthResponse authResponse = null;

        //TODO: загрузка только для тек драйвера ----------------------------------------------
        StatusChangedManager scManager = new StatusChangedManager(ctx);
        List<StatusChanged> statusChangerList = scManager.getByUserName(email);
        if (statusChangerList != null) {
            for (StatusChanged sc : statusChangerList) {

                UpdateStatusRequest updateStatusRequest = new UpdateStatusRequest(
                        email, sessionID, sc);
                HttpService<AuthResponse, UpdateStatusRequest> httpService = new HttpService<>(
                        AuthResponse.class);
                authResponse = httpService.Post(updateStatusUrl,
                        updateStatusRequest);

                if (authResponse.getStatus().equals("SUCCESS")) {
                    scManager.delete(sc.getTaskID());
                }
            }
        }


}
```

отдельно я объявил интерфейс слушателя

```
public interface TaskLoadListener {

    public int loadProgress(int progress);

    public void loadCompleted();

    public void wasError();

}
```

который реализует активити. Обращение из asynTask к активити происходит посредством реализации интерфейса. Как из этой схемы убрать интерфейс слушателя и сделать загрузку по стандартам android разработки ?

Answer (score 2):

Это не совсем верное архитектурное решение. При реализации данной задаче следует воспользоваться следующей связкой: База данных - Cursor - CursorAdapter - Expandedlistview. Для получения Cursor следует воспользоваться CursorLoader. А так, как CursorLoader является подклассом AsyncTaskLoader он уже использует AsyncTask для работы с данными в отдельном потоке.